# Two-factor Authentication for Service Fabric Explorer?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Anyone have insight on how to implement Two-Factor Authentication when using Service Fabric Explorer to access a Service Fabric cluster in Azure?

I currently have it secured with a client certificate but I haven't found ways to add another type of authentication to go with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster):

> When a client connects to a Service Fabric cluster node, the client can be authenticated and secure communication established **using certificate security or Azure Active Directory (AAD)**. This authentication ensures that only authorized users can access the cluster and deployed applications and perform management tasks. Certificate or AAD security must have been previously enabled on the cluster when the cluster was created. For more information on cluster security scenarios, see Cluster security. If you are connecting to a cluster secured with certificates, set up the client certificate on the computer that connects to the cluster.

It doesn't support MFA, I'd recommend checking out [Service Fabric cluster security scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security)

You could also implement MFA on the AAD level and then using the AAD to authenticate to Service Fabric

Comment: That's how I was reading it, too, that it's certs OR AAD.  But I didn't think about switching to AAD auth and making AAD MFA.  Thanks!